# How do I get only the values insided an array on a texview

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: My Data Structure in firebase firestore]

[image: the array appearing in textview]

I've been trying to show my array of foods on a textview from my `Firestore Database`. I have been able to view the array on the textview but it is not readable by lame readers, they show in the array braces and the curly brackets. I want to extract the values like produName, Quantity, etc independently

Below is my Model class and Activity class.

```
public class Request {
private String phone;
private String name;
private String address;
private String total;
private String status;
private List<HashMap<String, String>> foods; //list of food orders
private @ServerTimestamp Date timestamp;

public Request() {
}

public Request(String phone, String name, String address, String total, List<HashMap<String, String>> foods) {
    this.phone = phone;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.total = total;
    this.foods = foods;
    this.status = "0"; //Default is 0, 0: Place, 1: Shipping, 2: Shipped
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(String total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public List<HashMap<String, String>> getFoods() {
    return foods;
}

public void setFoods(List<HashMap<String, String>> foods) {
    this.foods = foods;
}

public Date getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

**MY ACTIVITY CLASS, I implemented call to firestore at onStart()**

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Request> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Request>()
            .setQuery(query, Request.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Request, MainActivity.DataViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MainActivity.DataViewHolder dataViewHolder, int i, @NonNull final Request mainMenuItem) {
            dataViewHolder.setData(mainMenuItem.getTotal(), mainMenuItem.getName(), mainMenuItem.getStatus(), mainMenuItem.getPhone(),
                    mainMenuItem.getAddress(), mainMenuItem.getTimestamp(), mainMenuItem.getFoods());}


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MainActivity.DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.order_layout, parent, false);
            return new MainActivity.DataViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
}

public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private View view;

    DataViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
    }


    void setData(String orderTotalValue, String nameOfPerson, String dataOrderStatus, String dataOrderPhone, String dataOrderAddress,
                 Date dataDateAndTime, final List<HashMap<String,String>>foodsOrdered) {
        TextView orderTotal = view.findViewById(R.id.order_total);
        TextView orderStatus = view.findViewById(R.id.order_status);
        TextView orderPhone = view.findViewById(R.id.order_phone);
        TextView orderAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.order_address);
        TextView orderName = view.findViewById(R.id.order_name);
        TextView orderDateAndTime = view.findViewById(R.id.order_dateTime);
        TextView orderFoods = view.findViewById(R.id.order_foods);

        orderTotal.setText(orderTotalValue);
        orderStatus.setText(convertCodeToStatus(dataOrderStatus));
        orderPhone.setText(dataOrderPhone);
        orderAddress.setText(dataOrderAddress);
        orderName.setText(nameOfPerson);
        orderDateAndTime.setText(dataDateAndTime.toString());

        //what i must do to foods array when it comes and then finally is attached to the textview!
        orderFoods.setText(foodsOrdered.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The `foods` variable is not a `String` but a `Hashmap`, as mentioned in the error.

Comment: try to change `private List<String> foods;` with `private List<HashMap<String,String>> foods;`

Comment: Thank you @Hanzala,  I would like to know, can i make it appear more orderly? an example will do big brother

Comment: I think you got answer

Comment: update your question what you've changed and what needs to be updated

Comment: thank you for bringing it to memory. I've done that bother. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a model class (OrderData) with this parameters discount, price, productId, productName, quantity and replace in ActualFoodRequest class

```
private List<String> foods; //list of food orders
```

with this

```
private List<OrderData> foods;
```

Comment: get list of orderData from request object (request.getFoods) and then loop order list to get all order data.